# Why Does Blender Keep Crashing When I Try to Run a "Mesh Object From Scratch" Script?

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, bmesh

I'm trying to create a cylinder with vertices all throughout the tubing. A normal cylinder does not have these vertices, so I decided to create a mesh object from scratch. After finally cleaning up a few logic and syntax errors, I clicked "run scipt" and Blender crashed. This keeps happening every time I run it.  I'm convinced that I might need to use bmesh, but I don't quite know how. Here's the code:

```
import bpy
from math import pi, cos, sin


radius = 1
length = 4
slicesAcross = 3
slicesAround = 4
verts = []
edges = []
faces = []
for i in range(slicesAcross):
    for j in range(slicesAround):
        angle = 2*pi*j/(slicesAround-1)
        v1 = slicesAcross*(i/slicesAcross - 1)
        v2 = radius * cos(angle)
        v3 = radius * sin(angle) 
        
        verts.append([v1, v2, v3])
   
#want 01, 12, 23, 30   
#     45, 56, 67, 74
#     89, 910, 1011, 118   
for i in range(slicesAcross):
    for j in range(slicesAround):
        index1 = i + j
        index2 = i + j + 1
        if index2 == (i+1)*slicesAround:
            index2 = i*slicesAround
        edge = [index1, index2]
        edges.append(edge)  
#for i in range of number of faces (added 2 for the two circle faces)        
for i in range(slicesAround*(slicesAcross - 1) + 2):
    face = []
    if i == 0:
        #make face out of first slicesAround edges:
        for j in range(slicesAround):
            face.append(edges[j][0])
        
    elif i == slicesAround*(slicesAcross - 1) + 1:
        #make face out of last slicesAround edges:
        for j in range(slicesAround):
            face.append(edges[slicesAround*(slicesAcross - 1) + 2 - slicesAround + j][0])
    else:
        #make face out of two opposing edges:
        for j in range(slicesAround*(slicesAcross - 1)):
            #want to connect edges j and j + slicesAround 
            face.append([edges[j][0], edges[j][1], edges[j + slicesAround][0], edges[j + slicesAround][1]])
            
    faces.append(tuple(face))



mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MultiplexCylinder")
multiplexCylinder = bpy.data.objects.new("MultiplexCylinder", mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(multiplexCylinder)
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
```

EDIT: Here's a picture of what it should look like:
[image]

EDIT: Script has been completed!:

```
import bpy
from math import pi, cos, sin

radius = 1
length = 4
slicesAcross = 5
slicesAround = 5

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []
for i in range(slicesAcross):
    for j in range(slicesAround):
        angle = 2 * pi * j / slicesAround
        v1 = length * (i / (slicesAcross - 1)) - length/2
        v2 = radius * cos(angle)
        v3 = radius * sin(angle)

        verts.append([v1, v2, v3])
        
        index1 = slicesAround * i + j
        index2 = slicesAround * i + j + 1
        if index2 == (i + 1) * slicesAround:
            index2 = i * slicesAround
        edge = [index1, index2]
        edges.append(edge)


# for i in range of number of faces (added 2 for the two circle faces)
for i in range(slicesAround * (slicesAcross - 1) + 2):
    face = []
    if i == 0:
        # make face out of first slicesAround edges:
        for j in range(slicesAround):
            face.append(edges[j][0])

    elif i == slicesAround * (slicesAcross - 1) + 1:
        # make face out of last slicesAround edges:
        for j in range(slicesAround):
            face.append(edges[slicesAround * (slicesAcross) - slicesAround + j][0])

    else:
        face = [edges[i - 1][0], edges[i - 1][1], edges[i - 1 + slicesAround][1], edges[i - 1 + slicesAround][0]]

    faces.append(tuple(face))



mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MultiplexCylinder")
multiplexCylinder = bpy.data.objects.new("MultiplexCylinder", mesh)
col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
col.objects.link(multiplexCylinder)
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
```

Comment: can you please share a link to the image of the shape you are trying to replicate?

Comment: do you get any error messages or stack traceback?  Those might be useful.  I would speculate that your call to from_pydata is crashing because you've somehow fed it bad input, but it's hard to tell just by looking.

Comment: @Aster17 Image uploaded! I think there's an issue with my vertices or faces. I'll keep trying to debug.

Comment: @MartyFouts The system console isn't displaying any errors. I think you're right. I tried creating a simpler mesh object (cube). Feeding the from_pydata call also caused blender to creash upon bad input. However, with correct input, it ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start Blender from the command line you get this:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 59, in 
  File "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 485, in from_pydata
    self.polygons.foreach_set("vertices", vertex_indices)
TypeError: couldn't access the py sequence
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF65851CA70
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00004284
```

If we print the faces list before the call to from_pydata():

```
print(faces)
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
```

You can see your list generation didn't go as planned:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), ([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5], [4, 5, 5, 6]), (3, 4, 2, 3)]
```

I rewrote your script a little to make it render correctly:

```
import bpy
from math import pi, cos, sin

capFaces=True

radius = 1
length = 4
slicesAcross = 4
slicesAround = 5
verts = []
faces = []

ring = []
# Lets build 1 cross-section
for i in range(slicesAround):
    angle = 2*pi*i/(slicesAround)
    v2 = radius * cos(angle)
    v3 = radius * sin(angle) 
    ring.append([0, v2, v3])

# now create the verts
for i in range(slicesAcross):
    v1 = slicesAcross*(i/slicesAcross)
    verts += ([ [v1,]+ x[1:3] for x in ring])

for i in range(slicesAcross - 1):
    s = i*slicesAround
    for v in range(slicesAround):
        faces.append( [ v+s, (v+1)%slicesAround+s, 
                       (v+1)%slicesAround+slicesAround+s,
                       v+slicesAround+s  ] )
   
if capFaces:
    cap=[f for f in range(slicesAround-1, -1, -1)]
    faces.append(cap)
    cap=[f for f in range(slicesAround*(slicesAcross - 1), slicesAround*(slicesAcross))]
    faces.append(cap)

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MultiplexCylinder")
multiplexCylinder = bpy.data.objects.new("MultiplexCylinder", mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(multiplexCylinder)

mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
```

Comment: Hi. I see now that my list was incorrect. I have fixed the list to how I want it now. Thanks for the response

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, you can upvote it. If it fully answered your question you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I need some more reputation points to upvote, but I did accept your answer. I'm surprised you beat me to it! I also completed it in a different way. You can check how I wrote it for fun if you want, but it looks like your code is shorter and probably more efficient. Thanks!